# Timeout for component unmount

Tags: reactjs

Okay, I have an idea about making comfortable and native page transitions with React. I made an example of how pages must transition between themselves - [you can check it here](https://jsfiddle.net/eub007xr/).

And then I started to programming it with React. And I have stalled.

Let's say I have a component Scene:

```
export default class Scene extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      beforeUnmount: false
    }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={ classNames({ "scene-container": true, "scene-unmount": this.state.beforeUnmount })}
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color}}>

        <h1 style={{ marginTop: "25%", textAlign: "center" }}> Scene { this.props.id } </h1>
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and a TestPage view that uses this Scene (AnotherTestPage is mostly the same):

```
export default class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet
          title={`Scene ${this.props.params.id}`}
          meta={[{name: 'description', content: 'Index page'}]}
        />

        <Scene id={ this.props.params.id } color= {`#${this.props.params.color}`}>
          <DefaultLink to="/" text="Go to Index" />
          <DefaultLink to="/another" text="Go to Another" />
        </Scene>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and the Router

```
export function createRoutes(history, store) {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route path='/' component={IndexPage} />
        <Route path='/forms' component={Forms} />
        <Route path='/scenes/:id/:color' component={TestPage} />
        <Route path='/another' component={AnotherTestPage} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Before current view is being unmounted, there must be fade-out animation of Scene, and at the same time next view should fade-in. And my problem is i don't know how to do it, how to timeout unmount of the view. Will be very thanksful if anyone will help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations in React are done with the help of React ad-on: [react-addons-css-transition-group](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

There's an example in React Router that accomplishes what you're trying to achieve (animation between page transitions): https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/animations

Comment: Yes, i've already researched that, but ReactCSSTransitionGroup, if i got it the right way, allows to use **same** transition on both routes, meanwhile i need **different** transitions on my routes

Comment: Okay, that's the point, I finally understood how it works) Thank you a lot!